# Find a maximum of $f(x,y)=\frac{\sin^2(x\cos y)}{x^2}\cosh^2(x\sin y)-\frac{2\cos y}{x}\sin(x\cos y)\cosh(x\sin y)$

Tags: functions

Let us the function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sin^2(x\cos y)}{x^2}\cosh^2(x\sin y)-\frac{2\cos y}{x}\sin(x\cos y)\cosh(x\sin y)$$
Calculate the maximum in the domain:

$$x\in[0,L], y\in[0,2\pi], L<\frac{1}{5}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is what I can get from looking at a drawing. It seems that the maxima is 0  at  four points . Could try finding the maxima on a ray along $<0, 2 \pi t>$ and so on , (the red rectangle is the domain specified in the question).

I'll check the drawing to see if I've  made a mistake somewhere.